# Getting Empty array when FQL querying the event_member table with uid condition

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-events

When I execute the following FQL query

```
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()
```

I get a list of events I'm attending. When I execute either of the following FQL querys

```
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = "{my uid written out}"
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid IN ("{my uid written out}")
```

I get the following empty object

```
{"data": []}
```

I want to query for my friends public events using. When I trying to do this using either of the following queries

```
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = "{my friends uid written out}"
SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid IN ("{my friends uid written out}")
```

I once again get the following empty object

```
{"data": []}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of authentication path are you using to get the access token you use to make that query? Are you sure it has the correct permissions?

Comment: I'm using the graph explorer tool and generating a token with user_events and friends_events permissions

Comment: Are you enclosing your UID in brackets? Otherwise, it works for me.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Can you give me an example of what's working for you?

Comment: `SELECT uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = 1234567890`

Comment: This query is giving me an empty data set when I enter it using the graph explorer, tested in Chrome and Mozilla.